# Altium schematic "snap grid" vs "snap distance"

Tags: altium, schematic

Could anyone give me a practical example of what is the "Snap Distance" on the Altium Schematic? I read the below but when I place a component I can't see any difference in movement when I change the value of the "Snap Distance."

Only if I change the "Snap Grid" value the movement of the object changes. Also I use the same numbers which shows the example at the below link but nothing.

https://my.altium.com/altium-designer/getting-started/schematic-grids-and-preferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snap distance is how far the traces will snap together when near each other (it get's really annoying to route if this is more than a few mils) so you probably won't notice this as much.

Snap grid is everything snapping to the grid. (press G if you want to change quickly)

Comment: Thanks you so much for the example and for the advice about the shortcut "G".